# Objective c - Create a tutorial bubble that will hide in background click

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

[image]

(First - i'm sorry about my english:).

I want to create a tutorial bubble that will pop up in some situations while using my app.
I need this popup to disappear when clicking or scrolling on every view in my VC, and i need that these buttons to do what they need to do in this click event and not only dismiss the pop up so then we will need to click on the buttons again.

I have 2 ways to do it, but every one of them have some disadvantage.

1. the popup view will have a transparent view with frame of the whole VC. this background view will dismiss the pop up in its touchBegin event.
   but like that i can't click ob my buttons that below this popup background view.
2. the second option is to create the pop up without the background transparent background, so all the buttons will be clickable.
   but in this situation i don't know how to listen all the buttons click event or table scroll event so i can dismiss the popup.

Comment: Did you find any nice way how to do the tutorial bubbles? Ideally some library?